# Laravel loaded relation, called dynamically will not allow ->count() when called in Blade except when in @dd()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

A bit of a weird problem, I'm probably missing something obvious.

I have the following object:

```
App\Models\Category {#2253 ▼
  +guarded: []
  +timestamps: false
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "categories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "children" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2254 ▶}
    "translations" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2212 ▶}
    "actions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2257 ▼
      #items: array:8 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
]
```

In the blade the relation (in this case 'actions') is called dynamically in a loop using an array `$type`, which in this case returns `actions` and is then to return a count.

```
{{-- @dd($parent_category->{$type['name']}->count()) --}}

{{$parent_category->{$type['name']}->count()}}
```

In my understanding this should totally work, except it gives the error: `Call to a member function count() on null`

The weird thing is if I check it with the commented-out @dd, it totally works and returns `8` like it should!

Also if I just write out `{{$parent_category->actions->count()}}` it works too.

I don't understand why Blade isn't accepting `{$type['name']}`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you do your dd in a loop and it returns 8 at the first loop but you get the error when you run your code without dd. It means that sometimes `$parent_category->{$type['name']}` is null and you try to count on null.

Maybe you can try with optional():

```
{{optional($parent_category->{$type['name']})->count()}}
```

Like that when it's null it won't try to count and you won't get the error anymore.